# how to fix unrecognized GUID error in form after WFFM upgrade

Tags: wffm, upgrade

the issue is the tracking field that was messed up during upgrade to the new WFFM version....
I've found a blog post below explaining the issue. Now I'm looking for a way to automate the fix.

https://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/26/sitecore-linkdatabase-unrecognized-guid-format/

I could use a powershell script, but I've logged a support ticket with sitecore to find a more standard approach.
Does anyone have a clean way to fix this?

FYI here are the field values before and after the fix (in case others want to write a script):

raw values before fix:

```
<tracking>  
<event name="Field Changed" />  
<event name="Field Completed" /> 
<event name="Field Not Completed" />  
<event name="Field Out of Boundary" />  
<event name="Invalid Field Syntax" />
</tracking>
```

raw values afer fix:

```
<tracking>
<event id="{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}" name="Field Not Completed" />
<event id="{F3D7B20C-675C-4707-84CC-5E5B4481B0EE}" name="Field Out of Boundary" />
<event id="{844BBD40-91F6-42CE-8823-5EA4D089ECA2}" name="Invalid Field Syntax" />
<event id="{AA3AE715-E87D-4B4D-80C7-4290546F770F}" name="Field Changed" />
<event id="{F0113A93-570A-4F69-8C7C-BA08037D1E34}" name="Field Completed" />
</tracking>
```

Comment: A PowerShell script seems like a fine way to solve this issue. It looks like it could be just a straightforward string replace, searching for the various event names, which could be pulled from the event items themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an admin page to fix the issue specifically for WFFM forms.
you should change the dictionary to include/exclude the necessary changes for your specific situation. Add this as an aspx page below /sitecore/admin.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
```

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
     private bool authorized = false;
    private string UnauthorizedMessage = "You are not authorized to view this page";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (!(true
            //&& Request.IsSecureConnection // Check for HTTPS          
              && Request.UserHostAddress == "127.0.0.1"
              && Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn
              && Sitecore.Context.IsAdministrator
            //&& Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole(@"sitecore\Developer") //check for specific role
            ))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            Response.Write(UnauthorizedMessage);
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            Response.End();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            authorized = true;
        }

    }     

    protected void FixFields_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!authorized)
        {
            output.InnerHtml = string.Format("<div style=\"color:red;\">{0}", UnauthorizedMessage);
            return;
        }
        ID formTemplateId = new ID("{FFB1DA32-2764-47DB-83B0-95B843546A7E}");
            ID contenTreeId = new ID("{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}");
            ISearchIndex index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
            string TrackingFieldName = "__tracking";
            int changeCount = 0;
            int errorCount = 0;
            output.InnerHtml += "<div>Starting update of fields</div>";

            Dictionary<string, string> replacements = GetReplacements();
            List<Item> indexResults = null;
            using (IProviderSearchContext context = index.CreateSearchContext())
            {
                indexResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                    .Where(x => x.TemplateId == formTemplateId
                                && x.Paths.Contains(contenTreeId))
                    .Select(x => x.GetItem()).ToList();

                indexResults = indexResults.Where(x => x != null).Where(x => x.Fields[TrackingFieldName] != null).ToList();
                if (!indexResults.Any())
                {
                    output.InnerHtml += "<div>No Form items found to modify. </div>";
                    return;
                }

                foreach (Item item in indexResults)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string value = item.Fields[TrackingFieldName].Value;
                        foreach (var dictionaryItem in replacements)
                        {
                            value = value.Replace(dictionaryItem.Key, dictionaryItem.Value);
                        }

                        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                        using (new EditContext(item))
                        {
                            item.Fields[TrackingFieldName].Value = value;
                            output.InnerHtml += string.Format("<div>Item - {0} - changed</div>", item.Name);
                        }
                        item.Editing.EndEdit();
                        changeCount++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        output.InnerHtml += string.Format("<div>Item - {0} - {1}</div>", item.Name, ex.Message);
                        errorCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            output.InnerHtml += string.Format("<div>Update of tracking fields finished. {0} items modified, {1} errors ocurred. </div>", changeCount, errorCount);

    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetReplacements()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        replacements.Add("<event name=\"Field Changed\" />", "<event id=\"{AA3AE715-E87D-4B4D-80C7-4290546F770F}\" name=\"Field Changed\" />");
        replacements.Add("<event name=\"Field Completed\" />", "<event id=\"{F0113A93-570A-4F69-8C7C-BA08037D1E34}\" name=\"Field Completed\" />");
        replacements.Add("<event name=\"Field Not Completed\" />", "<event id=\"{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}\" name=\"Field Not Completed\" />");
        replacements.Add("<event name=\"Field Out of Boundary\" />", "<event id=\"{F3D7B20C-675C-4707-84CC-5E5B4481B0EE}\" name=\"Field Out of Boundary\" />");
        replacements.Add("<event name=\"Invalid Field Syntax\" />", "<event id=\"{844BBD40-91F6-42CE-8823-5EA4D089ECA2}\" name=\"Invalid Field Syntax\" />");

        return replacements;
    }   
</script>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
       <title>WFFM 8.2 fix tracking field</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="trackingUpdater" runat="server">
    <h3>Update tracking field for WFFM form items</h3>
           <div style="margin-left:15px;">
            Click the button below to fix the Tracking field for WFFM forms.    This will add ID attributes to the selected items in this field.
            Modify the dictionary to replace more/less as needed.
            <br/><br/>
               <asp:Button runat="server" ID="FixFields"    OnClick="FixFields_OnClick" Text="Update form tracking field" />
           </div>
            <div id="output" runat="server" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;    overflow-scrolling: auto;">
           </div>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```